# Content Security Policy directive not working on electron

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, electron

I have tried a bunch of security policies to connect to our api but always get refused.

`Refused to connect to 'https://myapi...' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' https://myapi.../* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'".`

I'm using the default code from capacitor-community/electron, all I did was try a whole bunch of different options for the Content-Security-Policy.

```
export function setupContentSecurityPolicy(customScheme: string): void {
  session.defaultSession.webRequest.onHeadersReceived((details, callback) => {
    callback({
      responseHeaders: {
        ...details.responseHeaders,
        'Content-Security-Policy': [
          electronIsDev
            ? `default-src ${customScheme}://* https://myapi.../* 'unsafe-inline' devtools://* https://myapi.../* 'unsafe-eval' data: https://myapi.../*; script-src 'self' https://myapi.../* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src 'self' https://myapi.../* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';`
            : `default-src ${customScheme}://* 'unsafe-inline' data:`
        ]
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: try to provide code attachment also

Comment: its just the default capacitor-community/electron, all I did was try a whole bunch of different options for the Content-Security-Policy.

Answer (score 0):

- can only be a prefix not a suffix. Using `https://myapi.../` instead of `https://myapi.../*` works.